# Javascript Deadly Regex Causing Crashes

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

The following code crashes node without errors at the regex:

```
let userIds = [ '{"engagement":{"eng_type":"1","eng_src":"2","eng_tid":"194306103","eng_data":[]},"coeff2_registry_key":"0406","coeff2_info":"Aat8pXwCxGvsnFHaJutKYmmwLTh-aG_vTQqmWEMaVym4pjdotDI-SMDa1YxLQ5H_9rQ","coeff2_action":"1","coeff2_pv_signature":"937986085"}',
    '{"engagement":{"eng_type":"1","eng_src":"2","eng_tid":"194303673","eng_data":[]},"coeff2_registry_key":"0406","coeff2_info":"AasfSeYyurorlDFyaPqCUPRX0784D_aLBOvvMJ0YzwsU7UuR_LXUsYdcxiR97nEfxi0","coeff2_action":"1","coeff2_pv_signature":"937986085"}',
    '{"engagement":{"eng_type":"1","eng_src":"2","eng_tid":"1463867135","eng_data":[]},"coeff2_registry_key":"0406","coeff2_info":"AavqLu-BsgU63Ebs-RSixhiVZDp5X3poRMKo72xh6fXXZTw6MCIeYqXQoZlxWPvJ2wGn3ufeI-f6kKpuqYXsuuaU","coeff2_action":"1","coeff2_pv_signature":"937986085"}',
    '{"engagement":{"eng_type":"1","eng_src":"2","eng_tid":"100000155254627","eng_data":[]},"coeff2_registry_key":"0406","coeff2_info":"AauOQxAr_xsQg35Ui17aabTq982T9W4q7GbBpXooRf5BJkxV5o0hBer08Q0VDAvahAGy-3-rME__xHlqd_1Pjuh4","coeff2_action":"1","coeff2_pv_signature":"937986085"}',
    '{"engagement":{"eng_type":"1","eng_src":"2","eng_tid":"100000887401572","eng_data":[]},"coeff2_registry_key":"0406","coeff2_info":"AavSJuLZDb_zhEYZz2nehIQxKobJ5hBipKG-SZWQq2Ub1PhtHiCbRiaStnxIYzQ-o235UrDGlLmroVK0BFxXjWDz","coeff2_action":"1","coeff2_pv_signature":"937986085"}',
    '{"engagement":{"eng_type":"1","eng_src":"2","eng_tid":"1678641766","eng_data":[]},"coeff2_registry_key":"0406","coeff2_info":"AatUwJF_1EsSt6QMt1YwOugg_YMxKM26c4LJCU35YjFlxOYKsDDCE1ZzwtVVM3ISUvJMPbn7_5fgMuWKN1c_Xl-2","coeff2_action":"1","coeff2_pv_signature":"937986085"}',
    '{"engagement":{"eng_type":"1","eng_src":"2","eng_tid":"132201437","eng_data":[]},"coeff2_registry_key":"0406","coeff2_info":"AaviptP-8LbQZvLAQ4p-Se3Fvz3LR5qDLFt6n6WzloJSKiJ3WXLk5QbginTrAbtC1Jc","coeff2_action":"1","coeff2_pv_signature":"937986085"}',
    '{"engagement":{"eng_type":"1","eng_src":"2","eng_tid":"100001950501542","eng_data":[]},"coeff2_registry_key":"0406","coeff2_info":"AatXV0JQuWHc7vpKlxefpRFRkqwoj717Tvc1JO3F-fxcH_a3_kY6-wXeG1bTvm_ok3wQ6jISzS2VUWa-YWWAPC_o","coeff2_action":"1","coeff2_pv_signature":"937986085"}',
    '{"engagement":{"eng_type":"1","eng_src":"2","eng_tid":"205105603","eng_data":[]},"coeff2_registry_key":"0406","coeff2_info":"Aas7jsCGD2GN2mGZ32kpMLTMdx-ZXuSaF1XFwbrpu-SoJpkRLqatEMSi8Atf01lsn_E","coeff2_action":"1","coeff2_pv_signature":"937986085"}',
    '{"engagement":{"eng_type":"1","eng_src":"2","eng_tid":"508133028","eng_data":[]},"coeff2_registry_key":"0406","coeff2_info":"AasGxRKV3fi94reimenRvJGAJ5yWtZkWaKO5kHFf3sVQ3YKP-Z9hmmEynS76-loPoJ0","coeff2_action":"1","coeff2_pv_signature":"937986085"}',
    '{"engagement":{"eng_type":"1","eng_src":"2","eng_tid":"100003598913475","eng_data":[]},"coeff2_registry_key":"0406","coeff2_info":"AaufpNXk6hypPh2ha6eiguLL2MCBAd1CpobgdKV6BrXohx_mWIUC6vwSPV-0GhFdDYm5CddC7BkQAuT1QyOvQrMt","coeff2_action":"1","coeff2_pv_signature":"937986085"}',
    null,
    '{"engagement":{"eng_type":"1","eng_src":"2","eng_tid":"1497504778","eng_data":[]},"coeff2_registry_key":"0406","coeff2_info":"AavmYo7PGTGdZsc_PPOYGmsNMwjDTE-S5hDW7DrUoF7Y2EtpCggI0ul_M59zzKmqxV5kO3Pi6enGhkVSdX0kO0t0","coeff2_action":"1","coeff2_pv_signature":"937986085"}']

var userIdsAr = [];
userIds.forEach(function(element) {
  if (element != '#') {
    var userMatch = element.match(/eng_tid":"(\d*)",/);
    if (userMatch) {
      userIdsAr.push(userMatch[1]);
    } else {
      console.log(element);
    }
  }
});
```

Nothing gets logged to the console. I tried escaping the double-quotes. Didn't help.

Edit: Here's the code in a repl: https://repl.it/LvJs/1

Comment: And did you try adding `console.log(userIdsAr);`? Your code is working well.

Comment: if you log you userIdsAr it works: https://repl.it/LvJs/0 unless you have some other erorr.

Comment: revision of input data: https://repl.it/LvJs/1 . I didn't think it mattered if I shortened it a bit but there seems to be a problem with it.

Comment: Question updated with proper infos and code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex works. Maybe you wanna different regex? Describe what are you trying to do with it? If something crashes it's not the regex.

To see it works (at least what is written to do), try modding your forEach like this:

```
    userIds.forEach(function(element){
        if(element && element != "#"){
            var userMatch = element.match(/eng_tid":"(\d*)",/);
            if(userMatch){
                userIdsAr.push(userMatch[1]);
            }else{
                console.log(element);
            }
        }
    });
```

Your problem was not with regex, it's the fact some data doesn't match regex capture group, and `.match()` performs as described:

> An Array containing the entire match result and any
>   parentheses-captured matched results; null if there were no matches.

So I added a check if an element is "truthy" value.

If you modify the code a bit like this:

```
    userIds.forEach(function(element, id, arr){
    if (!element) {
      console.log("MUU: " + arr[id]);
    }
    else {
        var userMatch = element.match(/eng_tid":"(\d*)",/);
        if(userMatch){
            userIdsAr.push(userMatch[1]);
        }else{
            console.log(element);
        }
    }
});
```

You will see that you have 2 null elements in your data, you can find em by scrolling carefully over userIds array or using:

```
userIds.indexOf(null)
userIds.lastIndexOf(null)
```

Comment: Here is a 100% accurate representation of the data: https://repl.it/LvJs/1

Comment: Answer updated as well. You had a problem with the element being null which broke the code when you try to do element.match.